# Node Express-Gateway - Is there anyway to store API endpoints , service endpoints in DB (Redis)

Tags: express-gateway

Instead of storing api endpoints , service endpoints in gateway config , Can i use Redis database to store endpoint info .

Comment: What is your use case for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not how Express Gateway works. The configuration must be in [files as described in the documentation](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/configuration/).